# How can you access the on_press handler of a nested button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am currently designing a Kivy application, where I want to make as many of my components re-usable. I have some code which follows the following style.

```
<ListButtonGroup@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: 10

    up: up
    down: down
    list: list

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1.0, None

        Button:
            id: up
            text: 'up'
            size_hint: 1.0, None
            height: 50
        Button:
            id: down
            text: 'down'
            size_hint: 1.0, None
            height: 50

    ScrollList:
        id: list
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.8
```

I want this class to be used in multiple places, but I can't figure out how to make it so that I can assign on_press handlers to these buttons to use the class in multiple different areas for varying purposes and functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some properties for that like this:

```
<ListButtonGroup@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: 10

    up: up
    down: down
    list: list

    callback1: lambda: None
    callback2: lambda: None

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: 1.0, None

        Button:
            id: up
            text: 'up'
            size_hint: 1.0, None
            height: 50
            on_press: root.callback1()
        Button:
            id: down
            text: 'down'
            size_hint: 1.0, None
            height: 50
            on_press: root.callback2()

    ScrollList:
        id: list
        size_hint: 1.0, 0.8
```

After that you just use:

```
ListButtonGroup
    callback1: lambda x: print("1")
    callback2: lambda x: print("2")
```

Comment: Ahhh, that was the reverse of how I expected it do work (thought you would export the button, rather than import the callback), but looks like what I need. I will try it out and accept if it works.

Comment: @adzy2k6 edited the answer because I forgot the `lambda` (you can use `partial` also)